# Bug while running a Shell Command remotely from another server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, bash

I have 2 servers both ubuntu say serverA and serverB

I am running a shell command from serverA on the shell of serverB but it seems I need to do some escaping for the exact command to reach serverB. The command on serverB doesnt have & and anything after that. Is there anyways I can make sure exact command reaches the serverB:

I am doing this on serverA

```
ssh root@serverB 'processthis -a example.com/?a=1,2,3&m=a,b,c'
```

the actual command that needs to reach serverB is:

```
processthis -a example.com/?a=1,2,3&m=a,b,c
```

but the command that reaches there is

```
processthis -a example.com/?a=1,2,3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting a double quote around the argument to processthis.

```
ssh root@serverB 'processthis -a "example.com/?a=1,2,3&m=a,b,c"'
```

Comment: Thanks I tried the double quote approach and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should escape the & with an \ as it gets treated by bash.
Try this:

sh root@serverB 'processthis -a example.com/?a=1,2,3\&m=a,b,c'